# bootstrap modals won't show up because "$(...).modal is not a function"

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a modal shown with jQuery but it keeps sending this error:

> `$(...).modal` is not a function

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

I have added to the html file the Bootstrap and jQuery links.
Is there a problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Insert `jquery` before `bootstrap.js`

Also, change $ to jQuery

```
jQuery("#myModal").modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does you add bootstrap in the right order?

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
`<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/2Y2TF9Q/Untitled.png - this is the order can you help me with it?

Comment: I think you lack poper.js to using $(modal). You need add enough lib with right order